# Changing the tickmark labels in a plot call from a lattice-based call

Tags: r, plot, lattice

Is there a way to change the tickmark labels (the *two labels in red* below) in the `plot(allEffects(), ...)` call below?

I want to change them to `"A"` and `"B"` inside the `plot(m1, ...)` only (NOT via the `CO2` data or the `m1` model).

The `?effects::plot.eff` doesn't seem to provide much guidence.

```
#================ Fully Reproducible Example
library(effects)

m1 <- lm(uptake ~ Treatment, data = CO2)
plot(allEffects(m1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may change the `xlevels` of 'Treatment' in the model

```
library(effects)
m1$xlevels$Treatment <- c("A", "B")
plot(allEffects(m1))
```

-output

[image]

---

If we don't want to change the model itself, then create an object from the `allEffects` output and change the levels in that

```
e1 <- allEffects(m1) 
levels(e1$Treatment$x$Treatment) <- c("B", "A")
e1$Treatment$variables$Treatment$levels <- c("A", "B")
plot(e1)
```

Comment: A question of interest [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70469077/16762740).

Comment: @SimonHarmel i see that already answered