# Adding a vector to a data.frame in an asymmetric way in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

In my code below, I was wondering if there might be a way to add the `z1` vector to `data.frame` `d1` such that we can achieve my `Desired_Output` using Base R or tidyverse?

*This is a toy example. Thus, `d1` can have any number of rows and columns and `z1` vector can have any number elements. Thus, a functional answer applicable to other data.frames is highly appreciated.*

```
d1 <- data.frame(b = 1:5, SE = 2:6)
z1 <- c(2.3, 5.4)
d1$tau <- ""

Desired_Output =
 " b SE tau
   1  2    
   2  3    
   3  4    
   4  5    
   5  6
       2.3
       5.4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist`

```
d1 <- data.frame(b = 1:5, SE = 2:6)
z1 <- c(2.3, 5.4)
d2 <- data.frame(tau = z1)
dplyr::bind_rows(d1, d2)

#   b SE tau
#1  1  2  NA
#2  2  3  NA
#3  3  4  NA
#4  4  5  NA
#5  5  6  NA
#6 NA NA 2.3
#7 NA NA 5.4
```

With `data.table` -

```
data.table::rbindlist(list(d1, d2), fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: A follow-up of interest is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70477925/16762740)

Answer (score 0):

The d1 data frame has 5 rows and two columns. To add a column, it, too, must have 5 rows. However, because it is required for the z vector to occupy rows 6 and 7, those rows must first be added to d1:

```r
d1 <- data.frame(b = 1:5, SE = 2:6)
d1[6:7,] <- NA
d1$tau <- c(rep(NA,5),2.3,5.4)
d1
#>    b SE tau
#> 1  1  2  NA
#> 2  2  3  NA
#> 3  3  4  NA
#> 4  4  5  NA
#> 5  5  6  NA
#> 6 NA NA 2.3
#> 7 NA NA 5.4
```