# Add a named row between two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to add a named row between two data.frames `d1` and `d2`. My `Desired_output` is shown below.

I have tried a solution but it failed to get me to my desired output. Is there a solution to this?

```
d1 <- data.frame(b = 1:2, SE = 2:3)
d2 <- data.frame(b = 0:1, SE = 1:2)

a <- "obs" 

# Solution failed:
dplyr::bind_rows(d1, !!a := rep(NA, ncol(d1)), d2)

Desired_output = 
"   b SE
1   1  2
2   2  3
obs NA NA
4   0  1
5   1  2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help -

```
d1 <- data.frame(b = 1:2, SE = 2:3)
d2 <- data.frame(b = 0:1, SE = 1:2)
a <- "obs" 
d3 <- d1[1, ]
d3[] <- NA
rownames(d3) <- a

rbind(d1, d3, d2)

#     b SE
#1    1  2
#2    2  3
#obs NA NA
#11   0  1
#21   1  2
```

Comment: Sure, is it possible to avoid creating a `d3` object?

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, we may also do

```
rbind(d1, `row.names<-`(d1[NA,][1,], a),
    `row.names<-`(d2, nrow(d1) + seq_len(nrow(d2))))
```

-output

```
     b SE
1    1  2
2    2  3
obs NA NA
3    0  1
4    1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a an alternative solution, in case you want it in a pipe!

1. We wrap the whole procedure arround `add_row` from `tibble` package.
2. With `bind_rows` we bind both tables together and add a row before index2.
3. Then we have to change between `rownames_to_column` and vice versa.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
  
add_row(bind_rows(d1,d2),
        b = NA,
        SE = NA, 
        .before = 3)%>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("x") %>% 
  mutate(x = ifelse(x == "3", "obs", x)) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("x")
)
```

```
     b SE
1    1  2
2    2  3
obs NA NA
4    0  1
5    1  2
```